# set counter chapter with float

Tags: floats, chapters

I am trying to set a counter chapter with float like this :

```
\setcounter{chapter}{2.3}
```

I am getting this error alc Error: `.' invalid at this point.

Comment: Why use a float for a chapter counter and not use section or subsection to add a decimal?

Comment: Counters only accept integer values.

Comment: The `2.3` value does not make sense for a chapter. What should the 2.3 of a chapter be?

Answer (score 1):

Counters only accept integers values, so try this:

```
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\setcounter{section}{3}

\section{Your Headline} % This is section 2.4
```

Or

```
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\setcounter{section}{2}

\section{Your Headline} % This is section 2.3
```